# Track link shared to contacts in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm making app in which I share app download link to contacts. I wonder it's available or not to detect if some of them downloaded app from that link?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. So maybe it could be closed, not sure*. But I will still give you a hint. You can use Branch.io for deeplinking and analytics :)

Answer (score -2):

You can try link tracker and shortener:  https://bitly.com/

Comment: I was just helping, and post has tags "sharing".